# Updating Bootstrap on a big project

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I'm working on a project that uses bootstrap 2.3.2 stylesheets and bootstrap 3.0.0 *.js* scripts. Client side is outdated(a lot) and my first goal is to replace bootstrap files so I can start using the latest version, removing poorly written css and using updated classes and bootstrap v4 stuff.

So, what are my concerns right now? I'm worried that old bootstrap classes won't work anymore. Do newer versions support classes and css from older versions? Do I need to have anything else in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would compare the bootstrap 2.3.2 docs with bootstrap 4. I dont believe that bootstrap 4 offers any backwards compatibility for 2.3.2 stylesheets and the grid system seems to be radically different.

So I would say the first port of call is to check how you are going to have to update the site layout.

v2.3.2 documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html

v4 documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

---

**EDIT:** I did some reading up on Bootstrap 2.3.2 and one of the key differences is how responsive bootstrap works. Responsive features are not enabled by default in Bootstrap 2.3.2 but can be enabled by using an additional stylesheet.

If the site **is responsive enabled** it is probably based on the media queries you can see on this page: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive

Compare that with the [v4 grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and you will see that the sizes of the media queries are slightly different and that modern bootstrap uses a consistent 30px gutter (15px on either side of a column) as opposed to the inconsistent gutter width in v2.3.2.

The site may also make use of "responsive utility classes" to hide elements on certain screen sizes. If you wish to keep these then your best hope for finding similar classes would be on these pages:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/utilities-for-layout/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/visibility/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Alternatively if the site **is not responsive enabled** then the you may need to rethink your page layouts. Both versions of Bootstrap use a 12 column grid but the container sizes do not appear to match up.

#### Other things to watch out for:

- As noted in the answer before me support for glyphicons has been dropped. The v4 migration guide does suggest some [alternatives](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/)
- The button classes (and several other basic components e.g. progress bars) seem to pretty much match up however the styling of these and other elements with classes that remain in bootstrap 4 will obviously change
  -Dropdowns look like they might still work with the new js or with little adjustment.

I am sure there is more than this but thats what I could find on a quick skim through the old documentation.

Good Luck

Comment: the site is not responsive so that should save some work at an early developing phase. My ideia is to make it responsive however. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would first consider their tutorial on migrating to v4:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

For our project, the major problem was that the glyphicons weren't supported anymore so that we had to replace them:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components

Comment: A good alternative for Glyphicons is https://fontawesome.com/

Comment: As noted in my answer the Bootstrap 4 documentation and migration guide do suggest some [alternatives](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/)

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO as links go dead or change over time. However, you can use that information to compliment and form your own answer. If you can't do that, you should delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Since there is not any code example, it have no point to copy the documentation...The answer is not wrong, but the question is to broad to provide a useful answer, with examples on how to do it.